# Security - Filter attributes when creating user with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, devise

My concern is about the possibility for a malicious user to add an extra parameter when he registers on my site. I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and Devise 2.1.2. I have a class `User` with an `admin` attribute

*user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :trackable,
     :validatable, :token_authenticatable, :lockable
end
```

*schema.rb*

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.boolean  "admin"
  t.string   "email",                                  :null => false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
  # other devise columns are not relevant for the question...
end
```

I'm using the provided `Devise::RegistrationsController` for the registration of a User, and a custom view with `email` and `password`:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form_line">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email' %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="form_line">
    <%= f.label :password, 'Password' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="form_line">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Password confirmation' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Register", class: 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I works perfectly, but a if a malicious user adds a parameter `admin` with value `true` in the post request, the user is created with the admin privileges.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-10 18:46:15 +0200
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: { "user"=>{"email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "admin"=>"true" }
```

That's a security weakness in my site. Can I configure Devise to ignore extra parameters (I need only email and password) when a user registers (or updates its profile, I think I'll have the same problem) ? If it's not possible, is there another solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to protect the admin field from mass-assignment. You should add this to your model:
`attr_protected :admin`

Read more here: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_protected

Comment: Thank you, it works. I've chosen to rather use `attr_accessible`, with the option `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` as suggested by Ruby on Rails Security Guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

devise provide the possibility to configure multiple models for authentication, which I think is a better way to get rid of the problem.

"Devise allows you to set up as many roles as you want. For example, you may have a User model and also want an Admin model with just authentication and timeoutable features.If so, just follow these steps:"

```
# Create a migration with the required fields
create_table :admins do |t|
  t.string :email
  t.string :encrypted_password
  t.timestamps
end

# Inside your Admin model
devise :database_authenticatable, :timeoutable

# Inside your routes
devise_for :admins

# Inside your protected controller
before_filter :authenticate_admin!

# Inside your controllers and views
admin_signed_in?
current_admin
admin_session
```

If you and anyone with similar concern, take some time to check out the documentation of devise and see if you like it.[devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)